# NavigationStack to TabView

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-tabview

I've spent sometime going over questions on Stack Overflow and couldn't find an answer.

I'm trying to navigate from a `List View` (similar to a Sidebar) to a `View` that contains a `TabView`. However, when I move to the `TabView` the `Navigation Title` and `Search bar` disappears. I tried it with `NavigationView` rather than `NavigationStack`,  a little better but ungainly white space. To replicate the issue here's the code:

```swift
struct TestTabView: View {
    
    @State var searchText: String = "Search"
    
    var body: some View {

        TabView{
            
            NavigationView{
                VStack {Text("Inbox") }
                .searchable(text: $searchText ,prompt: "Search")
            .navigationTitle("Inbox")
            } .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "tray")
                Text("Inbox")
            }.tag(1)

            NavigationView{
                VStack {Text("Insights")}
                .searchable(text: $searchText ,prompt: "Search")
                .navigationTitle("Insights")
            }.tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "lightbulb")
                Text("Ideas")
            }.tag(2)

        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct TestTabViewWithNavigationStack: View {
    
    @State var searchText: String = "Search"
    
    var body: some View {

        TabView{
            
            NavigationStack{
                VStack {Text("Inbox") }
                .searchable(text: $searchText ,prompt: "Search")
            .navigationTitle("Inbox")
            } .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "tray")
                Text("Inbox")
            }.tag(1)

            NavigationStack{
                VStack {Text("Insights")}
                .searchable(text: $searchText ,prompt: "Search")
                .navigationTitle("Insights")
            }.tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "lightbulb")
                Text("Ideas")
            }.tag(2)

        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct AView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack{
            
            VStack (spacing: 20){
                NavigationLink(destination: TestTabView()) { Text("Using Navigation View") }
                    .navigationTitle("Hello World")
                
                NavigationLink(destination: TestTabViewWithNavigationStack()) { Text("Using Navigation Stack") }
                    .navigationTitle("Hello World")
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A TabView can’t be a subview of a NavigationStack, it must be at the top per the human interface guidelines. You can create a custom one if you really need this setup

Comment: Try to rethink what you want : even if it could work, how the user would know in which navigation stack  he is currently ? One from top or one from tab view ?

Comment: Good points all. Will try to rethink k the navigation scheme